# Stop cron job via quartz plugin 0.4.2 in grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have grails 1.3.7 and quartz plugin 0.4.2 for cron jobs.

```
class MyJob {
   static triggers = {}

   void execute() {
       //some doings.
   }
}
```

Somewhere in my code I have dynamic scheduling of my job like that:

```
MyJob.schedule(cronExpression)
```

Every time I schedule new cron job it creates new one and it works together with previously created jobs. But I want to replace old cron jobs of MyJob with new one each time.
Maybe I was wrong in my understanding but I tried to add

```
def concurrent = false
```

It didn't help.
Is there any way to stop all jobs of some job class?
Thank you!

**UPD:** As I understand there is no such thing as InterruptableJob in this version of quartz plugin. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found way how to unschedule job and schedule another one.
First I've added a group for job:

```
class MyJob {
    def group = 'jobGroupName'

    static triggers = {}

    void execute() {
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

Also I've found JobManagerService inside plugin with very useful methods. But I was looking into source codes to get how it works correctly. After some time my solutions become in next code (maybe it's raw yet, but it works):

```
class MyService {

    def jobManagerService

    def rescheduleJob() {
        def job = jobManagerService.getJob('jobGroupName').first()
        Scheduler scheduler = jobManagerService.quartzScheduler
        Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(job, 'jobGroupName').first()

        if (!jobManagerService.unscheduleJob(trigger.group, trigger.name)) {
            log.warn('Failed during unscheduling job')
        } else {
            MyJob.schedule(newCronExpression)
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear sometimes which name and group required in service methods. So debug and sources helped me with this.